# SQL Compare 27 fields as 1 field

Tags: sql, substring, concatenation, ibm-midrange

I'm looking for duplicate records in a file there are 27 fields that I need to compare they are all in a row is there a way to compare they with out having each typed out (a way to substring out the record format data)

I'm using

```
Select RRN(a),
       RRN(b)
From   fileX a
Inner Join fileX b
    On RRN(a) < RRN(b)
       And a.FLD1 = b.FLD1
       And a.FLD2 = b.FLD2
       And a.FLD3 = b.FLD3
       And a.FLD5 = b.FLD5
       And a.FLD6 = b.FLD6
       And a.FLD7 = b.FLD7
       And a.FLD8 = b.FLD8
       And a.FLD9 = b.FLD9
       And a.FLD10 = b.FLD10
       And a.FLD11 = b.FLD11
       And a.FLD12 = b.FLD12
       And a.FLD13 = b.FLD13
       And a.FLD14 = b.FLD14
       And a.FLD15 = b.FLD15
       And a.FLD16 = b.FLD16
       And a.FLD17 = b.FLD17
       And a.FLD18 = b.FLD18
       And a.FLD19 = b.FLD19
       And a.FLD21 = b.FLD21
       And a.FLD22 = b.FLD22
       And a.FLD23 = b.FLD23
       And a.FLD24 = b.FLD24
       And a.FLD25 = b.FLD25
       And a.FLD26 = b.FLD26
       And a.FLD27 = b.FLD27
```

I would like to use

```
Select RRN(a),
       RRN(b)
From   fileX a
Inner Join fileX b
    On RRN(a) < RRN(b)
       And substr(A.RCDFMT, 100, 54) = substr(B.RCDFMT, 100, 54)
```

I know I could concatenate them all together, but that still means typing out all the field names, I just want a shorter cleaner looking selection.

Comment: You might be looking for `INTERSECT`.

Comment: INTERSECT will still require all the column be in the statement

Comment: This is just how SQL works. You could, through a procedure or outside code, generate a SQL statement and execute it for you since you are wandering into the world of Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view with the 27 fields concatenated into one field.

Create a logical file with the 27 fields concatenated into one field.

```
create view mylib/myview as 
select a.fld1 || a.fld2 || a.fld3 
...
 as allfld
from mylib/myfile.
```